# MySQLdb Python - Still getting error when using CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: python, mysql, error-handling

I'm using this code to create a database with tables in Python:

```
def CreateDatabase():
    global DB_CNX
    global DB_NAME
    cursor = DB_CNX.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {} DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8'""".format(DB_NAME))
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NAMES(NAME VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)""")
    DB_CNX.close()
```

But even if I use the syntax "IF NOT EXISTS" I still get in my console errors like:

```
 Can't create database 'names'; database exists
  cursor.execute("""CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {} DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8'""".format(DB_NAME))
```

This didn't happened in SQLite 3. I've tryed to use the syntax with `try:` and `except:` but still have the same results. How can I avoid these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is actually throwing a warning rather that an error.

You can suppress mysql warnings like this :

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
from warnings import filterwarnings

filterwarnings('ignore', category = mdb.Warning)
```

Now the mysql warnings will be gone.

But mysql errors will be shown as usual

Read more about warnings at -

https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html